# Webpack and React authorization 302 redirect on fetch

Tags: reactjs, webpack, asp.net-core, fetch, keycloak

I am using Keycloak authorization server with React hosted via ASP.NET and Webpack. When I do a build and host through ASP.NET I have no problems with getting authorized methods on the host. When I deploy the whole project on the server there are also no problems with React connecting to the host. But when I am trying to do localhost development with Webpack proxy to my remote server, than I recieve 302 redirection to Keycloak login page. I log into the deployed app before the fetch, but it looks like the proxy is not recognized as the same browser. I have the 'credentials':'include' statement in my fetch init.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with Kestrel-Keycloak and http/https security. It appears that when you use a proxy like Nginx, Kestrel doesn't copy the headers. The problem can by solved by using:

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders
```

in Startup class, Configure method.